# No orthometric height from external device in QField

Tags: qgis, gps, qfield

I have an GG04 Receiver from Leica, using it with Leica ZenoConnect, NTRIP and MockLocation in QField, antenna in QField is set to internal.

The Receiver is connected via Bluetooth, the shown height in ZenoConnect is the orthometric height, the one I want for my captured data. Unfortunately the height shown in QField is the ellipsoidal height. The switch "Use orthometric altitude from device" is only available, when QField uses the external receiver directly, but then I don´t have the accuracy of NTRIP and didn´t get any height, QField shows 0,000m.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You could always just collect points relative to the ellipsoidal height and do the vertical datum conversions after the fact.  This may be a relatively easy task if you are in the USA since you will have access to [vDatum](https://vdatum) and the necessary conversion files.

There are several recent posts to Stack Exchange for doing vertical datum shifts with GDAL and PyProj.  See here for starters:  https://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=vertical+datum+shift.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The vertical datum conversion in QGIS should be the last option,  cause often i need the orthometric height in the field. I´m located in Germany but we have a grid file (NTv2 Datum Grid Shift (*.gsb)) too. There is an option in QField to apply the grid shift. See [QField doc](https://docs.qfield.org/de/how-to/gnss/#altitude-correction-vertical-grid-shift) I stored the gird file at the given path and i´m able to chosse this one in QField but in doesn´t change anything.